# Kafka broker shutting down due to leader offset being less than replica's latest offset

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I'm currently running into a kafka kubernetes pod in CrashLoopBackOff

```
kafka-prod-4                           1/2       CrashLoopBackOff   2640       15d
```

because of with the relevant error being here I believe

```
[ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=2, fetcherId=0] Exiting because log truncation is not allowed for partition __consumer_offsets-5, current leader's latest offset 0 is less than replica's latest offset 4 (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
```

I start looking for `partition __consumer_offsets-5` as well as the replicas offsets to try to change the offset so this error doesn't appear but I'm having trouble finding `partition __consumer_offsets-5` to change the offset.

```
kafka-run-class kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list kafka-prod:9092 --topic sfoo-SfooEvent --time -1
sfoo-SfooEvent:0:472643
sfoo-SfooEvent:1:472390
sfoo-SfooEvent:2:170840
```

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3410

https://github.com/Yolean/kubernetes-kafka/issues/98

Some of the logs I'm seeing here https://pastebin.com/hDQCefY7

Has anyone seen a solution for this error? Do I have to nuke the cluster and start from scratch again?

Comment: `__consumer_offsets` is an internal topic ?

Comment: Yes, it's the built in topic kafka uses to keep track of everything I believe. http://wanwenli.com/kafka/2016/11/04/Kafka-Group-Coordinator.html